# How to convert a millisecond in a readable date format in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert milliseconds (which i am getting from an api which returns JSN data) to a readable date format. The sample code is below -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var d = new Date(Number("1429894800"));
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toString();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It returns - Sat Jan 17 1970 07:11:34 GMT-0600 (CST). But it should be the current date time. How to do the conversion?

Comment: Are you sure that's *milli*seconds? It looks more like seconds.

Comment: add 3 zeros to the end, that will put you at April 24 2015 :)

Comment: Yeah..i think second.

Answer (score 2):

If you want, approximately, the time "now" you would need to use:

```
var d = new Date(1429894800000);
```

(Notice I removed the `Number("...")` because you don't need to convert a string to a number when you can just use a number.)

which outputs, for me:

```
Date {Fri Apr 24 2015 13:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)}
```

But a better way to determine "now" is using:

```
Date.now();
```

For lots more information, go to a handy dandy page on the `Date` class here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date